Is the cartesian product of measurable sets measurable with respect the product $\sigma$-algebra?
If $(X, \mathcal{M})$ and $(Y, \mathcal{N})$ are two measurable spaces, we can consider the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$ which is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{M} \times \mathcal{N}$.
According to that definition I would expect that the cartesian product of two measurable sets would be measurable since the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a set is by definition the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains that set. So in this case since $\mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{M} \times \mathcal{N}$ then $\mathcal{M} \times \mathcal{N} \subseteq \mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$ so if $A \in \mathcal{M}$ and $B \in \mathcal{N}$ then $A \times B \in \mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$.
My questions:
Is this always true? (I can't find an example where $A \in \mathcal{M}$ and $B \in \mathcal{N}$ but $A \times B \notin \mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$)
Can we conclude then that the cartesian product of two measurable sets is always measurable? And if not, why is that?
Here the case of infinite product of $\sigma$-algebras is discussed, but I am only talking about the finite product: Is product of measurable subsets measurable wrt infinite product $\sigma$-algebra?

Yes, this follows from the definition of $\mathcal{M} \otimes \mathcal{N}$. The product $\sigma$-algebra is the one generated by the rectangles $M \times N$ where $M \in \mathcal{M}, N \in \mathcal{N}$. Since the rectangles are contained in the generating set, they are contained in the whole $\sigma$-algebra, so they are indeed measurable.
